# How can I replace all occurrences of a specific substring in java?

Tags: java, regex, replaceall

I am attempting to replace a white space in a string that occurs before a closing parentheses or after an opening parantheses.

For example the string "8 / ( 1 + 3 ) - 6 ^ 2"

Should be changed to: "8 / (1 + 3) - 6 ^ 2"

I am assuming this will use the replaceAll method but I'm unfamiliar with how to use this expression properly for my specific scenario.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: Just to be pedantic: you can't replace any characters in a Java string.  Strings are immutable.  You always have to remember to save (assign) the new string that's created, or you'll end up losing the changes.

Answer (score 1):

Parenthesis (open and close) are special characters in a regular expression. So you must escape them with `\`, which is also a special character in general in Java, so you must escape that with another `\`. Despite how odd it looks, you want something like

```
String s = "8 / ( 1 + 3 ) - 6 ^ 2";
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("\\(\\s*", "(").replaceAll("\\s*\\)", ")"));
```

which will first replace all open parens followed by any number of whitespace with just open parens. Then it replaces any number of whitespace and a close parens with just close parens. Outputs (as requested)

```
8 / (1 + 3) - 6 ^ 2
```

Comment: @Cyclone You're welcome. Just note `\\s*` matches any number (including zero) whitespace characters. Which is fine here, but may not be fine everywhere. If you want at least one (or more) use `\\s+`